# StackOverflowError in Recursive Method

Tags: java, string, recursion

I'm trying have a recursive method count how many instance the letter "e" appears in a given string. My test string is `Count my e's please!`. Here is the code so far:

```
public static int showE(String s, int count, int index)
{
        if (index == -1) return count;
        String e = "e";
        int i = s.indexOf(e, index);
        if (i != -1) count ++;
        return showE(s, count, i);
}
```

When I debugged the code, `int i` would remain at 9 instead of increasing through each call.

I thought that since that last line of code used `int i` as input, it would set `int index` in the method's signature to 9, 15, and 18 through each call for the test string. Once the letter e was no longer detected, I thought that  `int i` would send -1 to to the signature, and then `int count` would be returned back to the main method. However, debugging showed that `int i` would be set to 9 through each call leading to a StackOverflowError. How can fix this?

edit: This is the code in response to Stephen C. Sorry about the formatting:

```
public static int showE(int count, int index)
{
        String e = "e";
        index = s.indexOf(e, 0)
        for(int i = index; i = < s.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            if (index == e) count++;
        }
        return count;
}
```

Comment: Almost always the problem's with the stopping condition.

Comment: Why do you use a recursive method for that?

Comment: @Rob: I assume OP is experimenting with recursion, because the loop would be simpler to understand.

Comment: @Rob, I go with what feels natural at the moment. It's usually loops, but I've been on a recursive kick today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`String.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29) starts searching at the index you provide. So it starts searching at index 9, and finds an 'e' there, so returns 9.

Try starting indexOf at `index + 1`.

Comment: +1, but now the result will be *the number of e's + 1* (for `abcde` it will return 2 instead of 1). So now the return should be `return count - 1;`

Comment: @MarounMaroun No, `count` itself isn't changed, only the starting index of the search.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I orginally wrote the program with `index + 1`. I think I undid it in a scramble trying to fix another error. Praising you and kicking myself at the same time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I changed the code before this fix :)

Comment: There is still an issue with strings that start with 'e'. You have to initially invoke the routine with an index that is less than -1. So invoking with -2 works, but -1 or 0 won't work.

Comment: @Ashe - I caught that when I tried a String that began with e. Again, much appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

- There is a more elegant recursive solution to this problem that only requires 2 arguments in the `showE` method.  **Hint:** think of adding something to the result of the recursive call ...
- Recursive solutions to problems in Java have an inherent problem.  Java stacks are always finite, and Java doesn't implement tail-call optimization.  Combine these two, and it is inevitable that any problem that requires really deep recursion will lead to a stack overflow.

  In this case, this means that if you try to count the E's in a long enough string, you will get an exception ... even if you get the recursion correct.

Comment: This is the specific reason I try to stay away from recursion when possible, but as I said earlier, I been on this dang recursive kick lately. I will attempt this 2 argument challenge. If you see me again, I have succeeded.

Comment: I think I've figured out a method to do the call with only two arguments. I'm actually working on a 3rd solution to avoid the recursion all together. Please have a look-see and the 2 parameter, recursive solution. See edit of question for answer.